# If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $A^{T}A = A$, then $A$ is symmetric and $A=A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and $A^{T}A = A$, then $A$ is symmetric and $A=A^2$.

Let $A = [a_{ij}]$

Suppose $A^{T}A = A$.

---

Then, we want to show that $[A^{T}A]_{ij} = [A^{T}A]_{ji}$ (symmetric $A=A^T$)

$[A^{T}A]_{ij}$

= $[A^{T}]_{ij}\times [A]_{ij}$

= $[A]_{ji}\times [A^{T}]_{ji}$

= $[A^{T}]_{ji}\times [A]_{ji}$ (switched order)

= $[A^{T}A]_{ji}$.

I have showed that it is symmetric.

How do I show $A = A^2$?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric then $A=A^t$.

Comment: If $A^T=A \to A^TA=A \to AA=A \\\to A^2=A$

Comment: The matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric for every matrix $A$ (even nonsquare),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $A$ is symmetric we can also use the identities $(CD)^T = D^T C^T$ and $(C^T)^T = C$. Then

$$ A^T = (A^TA)^T = A^T(A^T)^T = A^TA = A $$

and

$$ A = A^T A = A(A) = A^2. $$

Comment: hahaha, one second faster, +1

Comment: Thanks alot, I understand. I think the way you showed symmetry is better